# How to get table column header text in Watin?

Tags: text, html-table, watin

I am using Watin for automation testing with IE browser. I am new to Watin. I got blocked in a  task of getting the column header  text for a table.HTML code for that table is something like below:

```
<table id="gvVoiceCallReport" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; height: 100%;" border="1" rules="all" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
       <tbody>
          <tr style="background-color: slategray; height: 20px; color: white;">
             <th scope="col">
             <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('gvVoiceCallReport','Sort$Caller GCI')">
                Text - Caller GCIstyle
             <th scope="col">
              <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('gvVoiceCallReport','Sort$Callee GCI')">
            Text - Callee GCI
            <th scope="col">
                <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('gvVoiceCallReport','Sort$Originator-Default Bearer Apn')">
                Text - Originator-Default Bearer Apn

            <tr style="cursor: hand;" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand';">
            <td align="left" onclick="window.open('TestResult.aspx?testSuite=Job.139.1_1504100010110027884023126', 'TestResult', 'height=600,width=900,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');">
            Text - 310;410;FFFE;9210;B9F
            <td align="left" onclick="window.open('TestResult.aspx?testSuite=Job.139.1_1504100010110027884023126', 'TestResult', 'height=600,width=900,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');">
            Text - 310;410;FFFE;9210;B9F
        .....    
        ......
        </table>
```

Header text for that column is **Caller GCI**.
I am able to get the text for values in that column by using something like that

```
string columnValueText = mytable.OwnTableRows[1].TableCells[1].Text;
```

When I am trying to get the column header text by making `OwnTableRows[0]` (Index  to zero), It gives me exception: array out of bounds.

Anyone, Please help me to get the table column header text.

Comment: I have edited the html code for better understanding the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  var gridTableRows = page.Document.Frame(Find.ById("ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ifrmReport")).Table("gvVoiceCallReport").TableRows[0];
  StringCollection abc = GetAllColumnDataFromRow(gridTableRows, true);

   private StringCollection GetAllColumnDataFromRow(TableRow tableRow, bool isTableHeaderRow)
    {
        StringCollection RowValues = new StringCollection();

        if (isTableHeaderRow)
        {
            foreach (Element e in tableRow.Elements)
            {
                if (e.TagName == "TH")
                {
                    RowValues.Add(e.Text);
                }
            }
        }

        return RowValues;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: As we know header is always on index = 0. I just gend head row to the function GetAllColumnDataFromRow and check for the tag <TH>. If tag <TH> exist. store that text into stringcollection.

Answer (score 1):

I took this piece of html. Paste it into index.html.

A code that I used :

```
        FireFox ie = new FireFox(@"D:\index.html");
        Table tb = ie.Table(Find.ById("gvVoiceCallReport"));
        if (tb != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Found table!");
            var value = tb.Text;
            TableRow tr = tb.TableRows[0];
            Debug.WriteLine(tb.Text);                
            foreach (var elem in tb.Elements)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Name : {0}, Type : {1}",elem.Name,elem.GetType());
                if (elem.GetType().ToString().Equals("WatiN.Core.Link"))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(elem.Text);
                    //elem.Text is current hader;
                }
            }
        }
```

And results in Debug output :

```
Text - Caller GCIText - Caller GCIstyleText - Originator-Default Bearer Apn
Name : , Type : WatiN.Core.TableBody
Name : , Type : WatiN.Core.TableRow
Name : , Type : WatiN.Core.ElementContainer`1[WatiN.Core.Element]
Name : , Type : WatiN.Core.Link
Text - Caller GCI
Name : , Type : WatiN.Core.ElementContainer`1[WatiN.Core.Element]
Name : , Type : WatiN.Core.Link
Text - Caller GCIstyle
Name : , Type : WatiN.Core.ElementContainer`1[WatiN.Core.Element]
Name : , Type : WatiN.Core.Link
Text - Originator-Default Bearer Apn
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hello Zbig K. Thanks  for the solution. It works fine in   getting the first row text  string.  But again the problem is when we have multiple columns. By getting text for Row[0], it simply gives string of all column header  text concatenated with a delimiter SPACE. Any suggestions for getting  text of selected columns  headers for first Row.

Comment: You can try assign result to string and make array by splitting them :   string headers= "1 2 3 4 5 6 7";
string[] str = headers.Split(' '); and then foreach

Comment: Nice suggestion, but the problem is in  the format of string. See what is get from the result is( Caller GCICallee GCIOriginator-Default Bearer ApnOriginator-IMS Dedicated Bearer Apn )      and  what I need is like ([Caller GCI],[Callee GCI],[Originator-Default Bearer Apn],[Originator-IMS Dedicated Bearer Apn]  ) type of strings. So spliting didn't help me completely.

Comment: I Updated first solution